# Get function that "gets" other get functions

Tags: c++, get

So my challenge is: create a function that receives all of the parameters from the other get functions, like:

```
int get_day() const {return day;}
int get_month() const {return month;}
int get_year() const {return year;}
```

I want `get_date()` that receives all of the above gets. How can I do that? For example:

```
int get_date() const {
   get_day();
   get_month();
   get_year();
}
```

Comment: *"I want `get_date()` that receives all of the above gets."* I don't understand what this means. Can you provide an example of how you would use such a function? How does it relate to the other functions?

Comment: do you want to get the date as string? int array? in date-time format? it's a bit unclear...

Comment: @shesharp I want it like a data-time format

Comment: It makes no sense to return a single int when you need your function to return 3 ints. Just return an array.

Comment: you can use time_t

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos That's a great idea, but how would i do that?

Comment: Have you performed any research? This is a well-trodden subject.

Answer (score 2):

You may pack the date like this:

```
int get_date() const {
    return get_day() + 100 * get_month() + 10000 * get_year();
}
```

Note, that this is just integer, that looks like date. If you print today's date, it will be the number 20190423, which is just the number 20,190,423.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, it makes no sense to return a single int when you need your function to return 3 ints.
Just return an array like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct Cal
{
    typedef std::array<int,3> Date;

    int day = 13;
    int month = 7;
    int year = 2019;

    int getDay() const
    {
        return day;
    }
    int getMonth() const
    {
        return month;
    }
    int getYear() const
    {
        return year;
    }

    Date getDate() const
    {
        return {{getDay(),getMonth(),getYear()}};
    }
};


int main()
{
    Cal c;

    for (auto &&i : c.getDate())
        std::cout<< i <<" ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

The code outputs:

```
13 7 2019
```

Also, it's best if you simply returned the actual members instead of calling the getter functions. Besides the `getDate()` function is also a member of the class.

```
Date getDate() const
{
    return {{day,month,year}};
}
```

Online code example: https://rextester.com/WPXX24681

Comment: Why is it better to return the members instead of calling the getters? I don't think performance is an issue here because any serious compiler will optimize the additional function calls away.

Comment: @FrankPuffer Why is it better to call the getters instead of returning the members?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I didn't write that it was better. I am only curious to find out why Constantinos thinks it is worse. In classical OOP tutorials (which I am actually not so fond of) it is often recommended to use getters internally to make changes in the implementation easier. Again, I don't think that this is a very strong argument.

Comment: @FrankPuffer: Sorry for the delay... Calling the members instead of the getter functions is much cleaner to read and write. What would you prefer if you were maintaining a code base? Furthermore, calling a member function forces the compiler to create more "unnecessary" instructions which can be avoided by calling the member directly. Give it a try at godbolt and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

you can use tm struct as in here: [std::tm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm)

```
std::time_t t = std::time(0);
std::tm* now = std::localtime(&t);
std::cout << (now->tm_year + 1900) << (now->tm_mon + 1) <<  (now->tm_mday);
```

don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: This has nothing to do with the shown inputs `day`, `month` and `year`.

Comment: now he can get day month year from ctime directly and cast into integer though since tm_year, tm_mon etc. are all integers

Comment: Yes but your answer doesn't even hint at that; it shows something completely different.

Comment: since @Dave2222 commented "I want it like a data-time format" I posted this answer. you can find it in the comment section under the question text.

Comment: Yes, I saw the question. But "it" is "the date represented by `day`, `month` and `year` members", not "the current date". Those are two different things.